# Exclude files in ant-migration tool while deploying

Tags: ant, salesforce, fileset

I am new to salesforce. We are using ant-migration tool. There are a few classes/dashboards/triggers that we are trying to exclude using file sets. All of the below folders are inside src.

```
 <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property name="src.dir" value="../src"/>
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" casesensitive="yes">
        <echo message="Inside file set"/>
        <exclude name="**/classes/Abs*.cls"/>
    </fileset>

<target name="deploy">
        <sf:deploy 
            username="${sf.username}.${org}" 
            password="${sf.password}${sf.securitytoken}" 
            serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" 
            checkOnly="${checkOnly}" 
            maxPoll="${maxPoll}" 
            deployRoot="${src.dir}" 
            allowMissingFiles="${allowMissingFiles}" 
            ignoreWarnings="${ignoreWarnings}"
            testLevel="${testLevel}" /> 
    </target>
```

It looks like I am unable to exclude the same.

Answer (score 0):

Never used filesets, sorry.

My Ant pulls project's structure from Git to temp directory so in the build.xml we just delete stuff which we know is pain to deploy. We still want these files in the repo for ease of use / repo completeness.

```
<target name="deploy_target">
...
<delete file="${src.dir}/workflows/Reply.workflow" />
<delete file="${src.dir}/workflows/Question.workflow" />
<delete file="${src.dir}/layouts/SocialPost-Social Post Layout.layout" />
<delete file="${src.dir}/layouts/CommunityMemberLayout-Community Member Layout.layout" />
</target>
```